# tensorflow custom loss function with additional input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

I try to build a custom loss function for a sequential model. In this loss function y_true and y_pred are used to calculate an error. When I try to replace the y_true tensor, so all the true values from the model with external true values which should be the same, I get different results (about half of the expected values).
To make this clearer, here is part of my code which is working:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = tf.square(y_pred - y_true) + tf.square(y_pred - y_true)
return loss

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=4, activation='tanh', use_bias=True)) # 1
model.add(Dense(5, activation='tanh')) # 2
model.add(Dense(5, activation='tanh')) # 3
model.add(Dense(5, activation='tanh')) # 4
model.add(Dense(5, activation='tanh')) # 5
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I now try to replace one of the `y_true` with an external variable converted to a tensor, I do not get the same results. The `input_scaled` is the same numpy array which is also used in the `model.fit` so I would expect that these two custom loss functions would produce the same output.

```
input_as_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.float32(input_scaled))

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = tf.square(y_pred - y_true) + tf.square(y_pred - input_as_tensor)
return loss

# ...as above...
hist = model.fit(input_to_fit, input_scaled, epochs=300, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback], validation_split=0.2)
```

I am using TensorFlow version:  2.0.0.
Any idea to give an explanation for the difference would be appreciated.

*Edit:*
I recognized that Keras is processing my input data with the standard batch size of 32 and therefor there is a dimension mismatch between my `input_as_tensor` and the `y_true`, which has a different size. I'll have to figure out how to substract the correct values from my `input_as_tensor`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set a seed for the model to use you will never get the same result even if you use the same code and the same data.

Comment: That's clear, but when I run my code ten times and then always get a similar result, I call this my correct result. Then I changed the code as described above, where in my eyes the same calculations should be happening, but my results are always about half of the values than before.